# How do I use the response from sendToDevice method of FirebaseMessaging to find which index in the given tokens array was erroneous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm invoking the method `sendToDevice` of Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in Cloud Function (Node Js).

I pass the token parameters with multiple tokens such as `[token1, token2, ... ]`

Then I received a `response` of type `MessagingDevicesResponse`.

The code is like this:

```
//Array of Strings. token1-3 are strings
const tokens = [token1, token2, token3]; 

await admin
       .messaging()
       .sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
       .then((response) => { // response is type MessagingDevicesResponse

         for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
           const res = response.results[i];
                
           if(res.error) {
              //* If error found on index i
              //*** Do something to delete the non-registered token

           }
         }
         return { success: true };
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(
           `Error while sending notification. Code: ${error.code}, Error: ${error}`);
         return { error: error };
       });
```

Now, as you can see that `tokens` variable is an array of strings.
Consequently, `response.results` also return the same length as `tokens`.
But the question is, does the indexes in `response.results` maps to the same index as `tokens`?

I mean, does `response.results[0]` means it is the result for sending notification to the device with the token in `tokens[0]`, and so on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the elements in the `response.results` Array are listed in the same order as in the `tokens` Array.

This was previously documented and apparently it has been removed. See the last comment of this GitHub [Issue thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/600).

Look also at this [Cloud Function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js), which does exactly what you are looking for (i.e. deleting the non-registered tokens)

Comment: do you know *where* this used to be documented? If so, I can file a bug to get it added back.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen According to Hiranya's answer in the GitHub issue it was at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse.html#results

Answer (score 0):

Better validate all the registration tokens and then delete the invalid ones, before sending already. One can post chunks of 500 registration tokens each and the "unknown" ones (if any) are not really "invalid", but do belong to another project. Generally speaking, this needs some house-keeping, eg. just recently wiped out 27.5% of registration tokens, because they weren't valid anymore.